# Catch all route to query database and send to controller instead of view

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Looking to have a catch all route the query the database for url slugs. I gather I can do the following, but I am lost on how to specify the Controller I want to use rather than generating a view:

```
Route::get('(:any)', function($slug) {
    $page = Page::where_slug($slug)->first();

    if ( is_null($page) )
        return Event::first('404');

    // want to send to a controller at this point instead of returning a view
    return View::make('page')->with($page);
});
```

Being relatively new to Laravel, is this the best way to do this? If not, any alternate recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could do it by calling your controller directly:

```
Route::get('{slug}', 'SlugController@call');
```

As pointed by Manuel Pedrera, make sure this route is you very last, because this is a catch all and Laravel will probably ignore all other routes coming after it.

And the controller

```
class SlugController extends Controller {

    public function call($slug)
    {
        $page = Page::where('slug', $slug)->first();

        if (!is_null($p)) {

            return View::make('page')->with($page);

        } else {

            App::abort(404);    

        }
    }   

}
```

Comment: Also, make sure that you put this route at the end of the route list, since Laravel will look for matching routes from up to bottom until one is found.

Comment: Good point, Manuel Pedrera, just edited to add your observation. Thanks.